# Register value followed by a capture group in a replace gives error

Tags: vim, replace

I'm trying to use vim to port an assembly language file to a new assembler. The new assembler does not support local labels. So I'm trying to insert the label name before each local label. But trying to use a register followed by a capture group causes an "Invalid expression error".

**Example input:**

```
LABEL_NAME:

        MOV     SP,#STACK_POINTER
        MOV     R7,#12                          ;WAIT LOOP (3)
12$:    MOV     R6,#255                         ;TIME WASTER
11$:    MOV     R5,#255                         ;MUST WAIT !!!!
10$:    RESET_WATCH_DOG
        DJNZ    R5,10$
        DJNZ    R6,11$
        DJNZ    R7,12$
```

**Desired output:**

```
LABEL_NAME:

                  MOV     SP,#STACK_POINTER
                  MOV     R7,#12                          ;WAIT LOOP (3)
LABEL_NAME12$:    MOV     R6,#255                         ;TIME WASTER
LABEL_NAME11$:    MOV     R5,#255                         ;MUST WAIT !!!!
LABEL_NAME10$:    RESET_WATCH_DOG
                  DJNZ    R5,LABEL_NAME10$
                  DJNZ    R6,LABEL_NAME11$
                  DJNZ    R7,LABEL_NAME12$
```

This, of course, works:

`:.,10s/\(\d\+\$\)/LABEL_NAME\1/`

After yanking the label name into register `a`, this:

`:.,10s/\(\d\+\$\)/\=@a/`

Gives me this:

```
LABEL_NAME:

               MOV     SP,#STACK_POINTER
               MOV     R7,#12                          ;WAIT LOOP (3)
LABEL_NAME:    MOV     R6,#255                         ;TIME WASTER
LABEL_NAME:    MOV     R5,#255                         ;MUST WAIT !!!!
LABEL_NAME:    RESET_WATCH_DOG
               DJNZ    R5,LABEL_NAME
               DJNZ    R6,LABEL_NAME
               DJNZ    R7,LABEL_NAME
```

But this:

`:.,10s/\(\d\+\$\)/\=@a\1/`

Produces only this:

`E15: Invalid expression: @a\1`

I'm using gVim 7.3. Ideally I'd like to know why I can't use register expansion followed by capture group expansion in a replace statement. But alternative solutions would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use expression in replacement part, you have to use expression in whole part, not hybrid expression.  this should work:

```
:.,10s/\(\d\+\$\)/\=@a . submatch(1)/g
```

short explanation:

```
\=          " the replacement will be expression
@a          " read the value from register 'a'
.           " the string concatenation
submatch(x) " (function) get the matched group from your :s command, x=0,1,2...
```

help item:

```
:h :s
:h submatch()
```